# MySQL How to Script to create indexes on all date columns in database

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-8.0

I have a lot of tables in the database that are using a datetime stamp - I need to create a script that will create indexes on all columns in each table that does not already have an index .

So far I can get all the columns of type date, time etc.. 
I can get all of the existing indexes .. but I am having trouble combining them , as I intend to

```
Select (CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' , table_name , ' ADD INDEX (' , column_name , ');') FROM 
MyIdentifiedColumns ..
```

The goal here is to create indexes on all of these columns of type date, timestamp where no index currently exists with a script - NOT manually in workbench .. So how can I do this ?

Get my Columns in the database that are of the proper date time

```
select col.table_schema as database_name,
       col.table_name,
       col.ordinal_position as column_id,
       col.column_name,
       col.data_type,
       col.datetime_precision
from information_schema.columns col
join information_schema.tables tab on tab.table_schema = col.table_schema
                                   and tab.table_name = col.table_name
                                   and tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

where col.data_type in ('date', 'time', 'datetime', 'timestamp')
      and col.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
                                   'performance_schema', 'mysql')
     and col.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
```

And to get all of the Indexes currently in the database

```
select index_schema,
       index_name,
       group_concat(column_name order by seq_in_index) as index_columns,
       index_type,
       case non_unique
            when 1 then 'Not Unique'
            else 'Unique'
            end as is_unique,
        table_name
from information_schema.statistics
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'mysql',
                           'performance_schema', 'sys') AND index_schema = 'mydatabase'
group by index_schema,
         index_name,
         index_type,
         non_unique,
         table_name
order by index_schema,
         index_name
```

Comment: *The goal here is to create indexes on all of these columns of type date, timestamp where no index currently exists* In a half of cases the index by single field makes no sense.

Comment: Did you calculate the implication of running such a script to create all those indexes, I mean, each index will increase dramatically the tablespace file size, other than block some processes during the index creation.

Comment: I understand there are implications of indexes - these are historical data records and they get updated with new records and each new record has a new date.now() so the record is at the end. The data is queried based on the date range - not by Primary key or any other fields nothing else. So if you had a table where you insert datetime and then 2 other values and say give me x from date to date ..
I just want this script so I can automate adding those indexes on all of these tables ..

Comment: @Akina in this case it makes sense.. just for reference - consider the use case similar to:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211801/calculating-duration-between-two-events-in-a-mysql-database-timeseries
Check out your comments .on your answer .. however I am using the query like this one here as it is faster..
https://pastebin.com/guiYHkT1

Comment: The solution is simple build stored procidrue . In that you make a temporary table insert you known coumns with indexes. Then you loop through all tiem column and check if they doesn't exist in the temporary table and then add the index in an preprared statement after all is done delete the temporary table

Comment: @nbk the process I know - the code posted above is basically the components of that process - I am having trouble putting them all together in one script .

Comment: yes i know that, the problem starts that i can't verify your selects statements, so that building a complex query withouit having any test data is quite difficult or evenimpossible. So the solution with the procedure, is not that complex and easily to realize. But as i stated before without verufying your select , it is also difficult till impossible to program that also. You understand  what is missiing ist the tables to test your querys

Comment: *just for reference - consider the use case similar to* This is exactly the case when you need a composite index (in all 3 answers!), and indexes of one field each for all fields do not make sense.

Comment: @Akina How can I accomplish this - if I know how to do this - I will know how to script for the other columns if I need them - I know any field with value of 0 and 1 has low cardinality and not really to useful to index. But how can I accomplish the task ..

Comment: If your typical query is `WHERE foo_id = 123 AND date BETWEEN...`, then `INDEX(foo)` is not nearly as good as `INDEX(foo_id, date)`.

Comment: @RickJames you are right in that regards , but I am looking for a quick way to add the index on the date columns in every table .. if you have 150 tables and you want something really quick , not knowing what has the index and what does not .. better to run through and at least add. Almost all if not all the queries are going to be simply Between begin and end dates. And All I am getting is you should do this or that - all fine points but none of those things gets the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The larger the table, the longer the `ADD INDEX` will take, unless you have a current version, which has a rapid add index.

Your code seems promising.  You could complete it by building a Stored Procedure to loop through the constructed ALTER TABLE commands to perform+execute them.

But first, run the stored routine to just SELECT the constructed ALTERs.  Desk check the output.  (And/or show us the output.)